# set focus to a datagrid row whose cell matches a given value c#

Tags: c#

I am using c# and have a datagridview control with data loaded on a form. I want to select and set focus to the row whose cell value matches a value in a textbox. How can I go about this.

Comment: It's a bit too vague... what if there are more rows to show e.g. one at the top and one at the bottom ? How to make them visible ? Also do you want to search in all cells on just the cells of a specific column ?

Answer (score 0):

This will match the first instance of value in the textbox

iCurrrow = -1

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)

{

```
if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Equals(TextBox.Text))

{
    iCurrrow = row.Index;
    break;
}
```

}

dgv.CurrentCell = dgv.Rows[iCurrrow].Cells[0];